# cannot access foreign key in table created by entity frameork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using mvc 4.5 and trying to create Events page each Event will have list of Event Attendees;  I add classes MyEvent and class Attendee

```
public class MyEvent
{
    public MyEvent()
    { 
       Attendees = new List<Attendee>();              
    }

    [Required]            
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Time")] 
    public string EventTime{ get;set;}

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Event Name")] 
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Event Place")] 
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")] 
    public string Description{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Host")] 
    public string Host { get; set; }
}

public class Attendee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Attendee(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }        
}
```

EF created the tables MyEvents and Attendees and Attendees has Fk MyEvent_Id pointing to Id of MyEvent table; the problem I cannot access MyEvent_Id in code while I can access the rest of columns ( Id and Name) the other problem is that the Attendees list of MyEvent Entity seems to be renewed over and over again and contains only the last attndee; I want to be able to get all attendees associated with an event to display all event goers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to access the MyEvent-object from your Attendee, however you are missing the navigation property to access your event object. Your Attendee class should look something like this

```
public class Attendee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MyEventID { get; set; }

    public virtual MyEvent MyEvent { get; set; }

    public Attendee(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }        
}
```

Your second question is not really clear to me. Entity Framework usually only reads the Attendees from the database when you actually access the entity. You should be able to iterate through the list of Attendees without a problem.